# Javascript Arrays within Arrays lost

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, undefined

I created an array of strings in JS.

```
arr1 = [];
for (...)
  arr1.push('aasfd');
```

Now I add this array to another array contained in some other object.

```
arr2 = [];
arr2.push(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

The last log statement shows the expected array.

```
[
 Array[3]
 0: "A"
 1: "B"
 2: "C"
 length: 3
 __proto__: Array[0]
]
```

After a while, some event handler gets invoked and it turns out the contents of arr2 are undefined. I am pretty sure that no function in the object containing arr2 is invoked between the two callbacks.

arr2 becomes

```
[undefined x 1]
```

No idea where the array arr1 contained within arr2 is getting lost. Am I missing something? How do I debug this error?

Comment: Please provide a [short example](http://sscce.org) of your problem.

Comment: Code is worth (1k - 24) words.

Comment: I am suspecting it is a gc bug ... not sure I will be able to simulate it in a sample program ... anyways will give it a try and get back in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit a bug in chrome which caused it difficult to debug the problem.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801